# Printing the output straight from makefile to a .txt file

Tags: c++, testing, makefile, doctest

I have a `test.cpp` file that test my class, then I have a `Makefile` that I use to run my program AND run my tests (after running the tests, the result should be written into a .txt file as well as into the terminal). This is my `test.cpp`:

```
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include "doctest.h"
#include "Weather.h"

using namespace std;

TEST_CASE("Random test") {
    Weather testt(10, 1, 0, "sunny");
    CHECK(testt.getAirTemperature() == 10);
}
```

And this is my `Makefile`

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
TEST_TARGET = test.exe
TEST_OUT = test_out.txt

all: program

program: main.o Weather.o myException.o
    $(CC) main.o Weather.o myException.o -o program

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

Weather.o: Weather.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Weather.cpp

myException.o: myException.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) myException.cpp

build_test: test.o Weather.o myException.o
    $(CC) test.o Weather.o myException.o -o $(TEST_TARGET)

run_test: $(TEST_TARGET)
    $(TEST_TARGET) >> $(TEST_OUT) && $(TEST_TARGET)

test.o: test.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test.cpp

rebuild: clean all

clean:
    rm -rf *o program
```

You can ignore everything in the makefile just look at `build_test` `run_test` and `test.o` Since these are 3 things that I use for this task. In the terminal, when I write `make build_test` an executable is created successfully without any problem, although when I move on to `make run_test` I get `test.exe >> test_out.txt && test.exe. make: *** [Makefile:24: run_test] Error 1`. So it says the issue is in the 24th line which is  `$(TEST_TARGET) >> $(TEST_OUT) && $(TEST_TARGET)`. My question is, did I get the idea of how I should print it into a file and a terminal wrong? Or how should I output the results the `doctest.h` provides me with.

Comment: That message is just make telling you that the program it ran failed (exited with a non-0 exit code).  It's not an error from make itself.  So you have to look at what program make ran and whether it succeeded or not, and what errors it printed.  That is, the output BEFORE what you see here (it may appear in the `TEST_OUT` file).  You haven't shown us that so we can't help you with it.

Comment: I doubt that your assignment is meant to have you run the test TWO TIMES, once sending to a file and once sending to stdout.  I'm pretty sure they want you to run the program ONE TIME and get the output to go both places.

Comment: Well unfortunately no matter how many methods I use nothing is appearing in the ```TEST_OUT``` file...

Comment: @Norbertas Before debugging your makefile, you should make sure that your program works. That is, run it from the command line and make sure it does what it should. Then run `test.exe >> test_out.txt` followed by `test.exe >> test_out.txt && test.exe` to make sure they work. Then you might want to try `test.exe | tee test_out.txt` (if [tee](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/tee) is available on your system). The point is to verify that the pieces work outside your makefile, before looking at your makefile for errors.